# Deploy React web app microservices environment

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, microservices

I have a back-end system running as microservices implemented in Spring Boot and I want to integrate a front end React app which needs to communicate with the back-end API. I want to deploy the applications in in-house Linux servers. Not using AWS or Kubernetes/Docker. What is the general pattern of deploying React application with considering HA (highly availability)?

Comment: first you should indicate where you want to deploy your microservices

Comment: @SemahMhamdi Thanks. I have updated information in the question.

Comment: since you don't want to use cloud services, you may need to consider multiple vms running react app behind load balancer.